# Very strange behaviour in a 3 way light

Tags: multiway-switch

Experiencing some very strange behaviour in a 3 way switch.

The 3 way switch in question controls the hallway light in my upstairs.  There is one switch at each end of the hall and a single LED 5” round light from Home Depot in the middle of the hall.  I installed the light about 5 years ago and it has worked fine until last week.  I hit the switch at one end and the light didn’t come on.  Naturally I flipped it a bunch of times and still nothing.  Cant remember if I tired the other switch at the time or what position I left the switch in.  Fast forward a few hours and now the light is working again.  I assumed the light was on the way out, I wasn’t happy but wasn’t too surprised. However, now I have noticed that the positioning of the 3 ways switches has changed.  Before this happened, when the light was off the switches would be in opposite positions.  When on, both would be in the same position.  Now just the opposite is happening.  When off, the switches are in the same position and in opposite positions when on.  My wife confirms I am not crazy and this has in fact flipped.  Can someone help me understand how this is possible? I have not touched the switches or light since install 5 years ago, haven’t added any circuits, nothing. House is 15 years old, near Toronto Canada. I have 2 young kids in the house so safety is a huge concern.

Thanks

Comment: That's a stumper. Have you had the switches out?  Maybe someone is using it to hide drugs lol, and put it in upside down  the last time.

Comment: That is strange, assuming it is an *ordinary* switch. If it is a smart switch of any time (timer, dimmer, motion sensor, etc.) then "anything" could happen. With an ordinary 3-way switch, I would expect most failures to be either "fail always on" (in which case flipping the other 3-way switch would turn this off/on but this switch would have no effect) or "fail always off" (in which case neither switch would have any effect). Fail "reverse" would be pretty wacky.

Comment: I think you're going to have to replace that switch. It will soon fail completely.